# Help wiring replacement Honeywell to Nest 3rd gen

Tags: thermostat

Need help with identifying wires on Honeywell TH9320WF5003, using Nest compatibility checker to replace with Nest gen 3

One of wires look like "W- O/B, not sure which wire it really is nest doesn't have this wire option?

On Honeywell I have wires going into C, RC, R, W- O/B, Y, G

Home has 5 zones baseboard heating and 2 zones a/c, replacing one of thermostats that controls both a/c and heat

picture of thermostat connectors, top right connector has me confused, looks like "W- O/B"
[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at both ends?

Comment: We need to see the wiring at the furnace/air-handler end as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://www.doityourself.com/forum/thermostatic-controls/596703-honeywell-nest-thermostat-wiring-help.html

I used following wire mapping from honeywell to nest and I have been up and running for a few days without issue

C = C

Rc = Rc

Y = Y1

G = G

R = Rh

W = W1

Comment: In case it's of any use: C = Common wire (used for electrical COM for thermostats requiring a 24VAC power source), Rc = +24V for cooling circuit (often bridged with Rh), Rh = +24V for heating circuit, Y# = Cooling (# indicates the zone, if more than one), W# = Heating, G = Fan